# WPF: How to combine Hyperlink and Popup into PopupHyperlink?

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, popup

Right now I have these three pieces:

```
<TextBlock Margin="2, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Hyperlink Click="UpdateHyperlinkOnClick">
        <Run Text="Some text"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>

<Popup Name="UpdatePopup" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Mouse" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide">
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle}">
        <TextBlock Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="600">
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=UpdateMessage, Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
            <Hyperlink Click="InstallClick"><Run Text="Some text"/></Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </ContentControl>
</Popup>

private void UpdateHyperlinkOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.UpdatePopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

I would like to get rid of Click event in Hyperlink, its implementation and having to name a Popup control.

Ideally I would like to have something like this:

```
<PopupHyperLink>
    <Hyperlink>
        <Run Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.UpdateIsAvailableText}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
    <Popup StaysOpen="False" Placement="Mouse" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide">
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle}">
            <TextBlock Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="600">
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=UpdateMessage, Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
                <Hyperlink Click="InstallClick"><Run Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.InstallText}"/></Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </ContentControl>
    </Popup>
</PopupHyperLink>
```

Any idea how to do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my first version of what I wanted to achieve. Definitely there are bugs here, i'll try to update this answer down the road.

With below described approach I can now write such XAML code and be happy :)

```
<popupControl:HyperlinkPopup Margin="2, 0, 0, 0" HyperlinkText="{x:Static properties:Resources.UpdateIsAvailableText}">
    <popupControl:HyperlinkPopup.Popup>
        <TextBlock Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="600">
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=UpdateMessage, Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
            <Hyperlink Click="InstallClick"><Run Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.InstallText}"/></Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </popupControl:HyperlinkPopup.Popup>
</popupControl:HyperlinkPopup>
```

This seems to be exactly what I needed for my app:

1. Ability to provide a text for hyperlink
2. Specify my custom popup for this particular hyperlink (it can be different for different hyperlinks - that's the whole idea)
3. No code behind for places where I use this control

Overall:

1. Defined custom control with two properties (Popup and HyperlinkText)
2. Defined XAML in Generic.xaml
3. Defined OnClick (implemented via iterating through UI elements - not sure whether it's easier to do it better)

Drawbacks:

1. By some reason both VS and Blend are able to visualize this control only upon opening VS/Blend for the first time. Once I compile it the second time it is shown as empty
2. Not sure whether it is the best way to implement something like this. Any ideas how to improve it?

Implementation:

I defined a custom control:

```
/// <summary>The hyperlink popup.</summary>
public class HyperlinkPopup : ContentControl
{
    #region Constants and Fields

    /// <summary>The popup property.</summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PopupProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Popup", 
        typeof(object), 
        typeof(HyperlinkPopup), 
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    /// <summary>The popup property.</summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HyperlinkTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "HyperlinkText", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(HyperlinkPopup), 
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    #endregion

    #region Constructors and Destructors

    /// <summary>Initializes static members of the <see cref="HyperlinkPopup"/> class.</summary>
    static HyperlinkPopup()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(HyperlinkPopup), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HyperlinkPopup)));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the popup.</summary>
    public object Popup
    {
        get
        {
            return (object)this.GetValue(PopupProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(PopupProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the text.</summary>
    public string HyperlinkText
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this.GetValue(HyperlinkTextProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(HyperlinkTextProperty, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

OnClick event is processed the following way (a bit hacky, will be happy to learn how to do it better):

```
/// <summary>The hyperlink popup events.</summary>
public partial class HyperlinkPopupEvents
{
    #region Methods

    /// <summary>The hyperlink on click.</summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The e.</param>
    private void HyperlinkOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Locate ContentPresenter
        var hyperLink = (Hyperlink)sender;
        var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(hyperLink.Parent) as UIElement;
        Debug.Assert(grid != null, "element is null");
        Debug.Assert(
            VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grid) == 2,
            "There must be only 2 children under grid in our custom HyperlinkPopup");

        var popup = (Popup)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, 1);
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HyperlinkPopup}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HyperlinkPopup}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Hyperlink Click="HyperlinkOnClick">
                            <Run Text="{TemplateBinding HyperlinkText}"/>
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Popup StaysOpen="False" Placement="Mouse" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle}">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Popup"/>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to avoid code behind in this case. However there is no persistent state based on which we can keep the `IsOpen` to true using a `Trigger` or a `Binding`. You can also invoke a Command and this Command should set `IsOpen` to true. However this requires some Command in codebehind, which is still what you want to avoid.

I've just thought of using `EventTrigger` in this case, that allows you to start an animation and with `BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames`, you can set a property to `true` or `false` easily. The problem is the `Storyboard.Target` should bet set. In a `Style` context, we cannot use `Storyboard.TargetName` and because `Storyboard` is not a `FrameworkElement` we cannot use a Binding with a specified `ElementName` or `RelativeSource`. The only way of binding the `Storyboard.Target` is using a Binding with a specified `Source`. Normally this is set to a `StaticResource` or a `DynamicResource` (or directly). So you should place the `Popup` as a resource with a specified ResourceKey (this is also the normal and recommended way we do). Here is the code details:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Popup x:Key="pop" Name="p2" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Mouse" 
         AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide">
      <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle}">
        <TextBlock Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="600">
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=UpdateMessage, Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
            <Hyperlink Click="InstallClick">
              <Run Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.InstallText}"/>
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
      </ContentControl>
  </Popup>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock>
  <Hyperlink>
    <Hyperlink.Style>
       <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
         <Style.Triggers>
           <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
             <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                 <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                    Storyboard.Target="{Binding Source={StaticResource pop}}"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Duration="0:0:0">
                      <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                 </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </Hyperlink.Style>
      <Run Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.UpdateIsAvailableText}"/>
   </Hyperlink>
 </TextBlock>
```

Note that this way the `IsOpen` is ***animated***. So to override it via setting locally in codebehind, you have to remove the animated value first (search for *How to override animated value in WPF*).

Comment: Thank you King King for your solution! My main reasoning for doing this exercise is to remove code behind and improve expression of xaml code. So, I really would like to keep Hyperlink and Popup functionalities somewhere nearby.